# Is there a way to implement a 'procmon' like tool with .net?

Tags: .net, filesystems, audit

we are currently in the process of moving a coldfusion web site from server to server.
In order to do that, we'd like to do some cleanup at the file system level. As ColdFusion is using includes, it makes pretty hard to figure out which files are really used.

One of the solution I found was to use Procmon from Sysinternals. With the right filter in place, it provides the correct information. However, I'm a bit worried about the number of events that will recorded.

On the other hand, the .NET FileSystemWatcher class looks promising, but does not handle the access event.

Finally, using the Audit feature of the file system seems interesting but does not allow to filter by process. Therefore, the log might get rotated because of too many events polluting the event logs.

Does anyone know any .NET class that could be used to mimic procmon?

Comment: with the right filter, and then a redudant-filename-remover on the output, the right amount of events will be recorded. :)

Comment: Are you sure that this is the way to determine what files should be moved? If you do it like this you are very dependent on the actual use of the site. It might be better to try and understand the web application.

Comment: @Erno - You are right. But we have a bit more than 3'000 pages that do have 4/5 elements on each page. Each element may (or may not call) series of include / template / custom tags files. Most of the time, it si quite easy to figure out which file to remove (e.g. by file extension .cfm.old, .cfm.bad ...), but sometimes, things are a bit harder. Hopefully, I was looking for a way to put together a service that would collect data over time and would be able to report all page / component that were not used for the last 6 month. That would give us a good base for cleaning up.

Comment: @Jaepetto, A a good way would be to use the original installer/setup program that was used to deploy the application... You would never be sure whether or not you missed something because it is just advanced trail and error.

Comment: @Erno - Unfortunately, ColdFusion is a scripting language like php. Files have been updated, added and removed directly on the web server over time. There was no real process in place regarding source management... :-(

Comment: @Jeapetto, being a scripting language is never an excuse for proper release management, on the contrary it's an environment like this that needs very good management. That said, I feel your pain... Keep a good backup so you will be able to add files back that you removed and start managing the sources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileSystemWatcher` relies on operating system features to provide events when files are changed. There is no such built in feature to notify of every access to a file. ProcMon handles that through a custom file system filter driver that handles the notification. It is not possible to write such a function entirely in C# as it requires some kernel level code running in a driver.

Unless this is a problem large enough to justify a large investment I would recommend using ProcMon anyways, spending time setting up the right filters.